# Filter data from CustomEvent

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have data in azure Insights saved in custom events formats. 
Now I need to create a dashboard page in my website that will pull data from insights and will show graphs on that data. 
Questions is that how I can filter data from the customEvents based on data saved there. like based on custom events or custom data.

Provide me any resource from where I can see that how $filer, $search,$query works?
I am here https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart but not looks like enough.

I tried to add filter like 
**startswith(customEvent/name, 'BotMessageReceived')**
in https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/events
but it not working. is says **"Something went wrong while running the query",**
I have customEvents which name start with BotMessageReceived

Thanks
Dalvir

Comment: please use analycis query and the api you metioned in your question, some thing like `https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/Your_application_id/query?query=events
| where timestamp >ago(5h)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update:
There is no like operator, if you wanna use timestamp as a filter, you should use one of the three methods below:

```
    customEvents 
    | where timestamp >= datetime('2018-11-23T00:00:00.000') and timestamp <= 
datetime('2018-11-23T23:59:00.000')


    customEvents
    | where tostring(timestamp) contains "2018-12-11"


    customEvents
    | where timestamp between(datetime('2018-11-23T00:00:00.000') .. 
datetime('2018-11-23T23:59:00.000') )
```

---

Please use this:

```
customEvents
| where name startswith "BotMessageReceived"
```

And if you use the api you metioned above, you can use:

```
    https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/Your_application_id/query?
query=customEvents | where name startswith "BotMessageReceived"
```

It works at my side.

Comment: yes it works with query.  Can we apply like operator in search. how we can do it.
Example if I want to query all records where timestap="2018-12-11" does not matter what is time. just want to query based on Date value

Comment: @FilmjamrMovies no like operator, but it has a contains operator, if it can meet your need, I can update my answer for it.